# How to take a screenshot of a WPF control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, screenshot, system.drawing

I created a WPF application using the Bing maps WPF control.
I would like to be able to screenshot only the Bing maps control.

I use this code to make the screenshot:

```
// Store the size of the map control
int Width = (int)MyMap.RenderSize.Width;
int Height = (int)MyMap.RenderSize.Height;
System.Windows.Point relativePoint = MyMap.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
int X = (int)relativePoint.X;
int Y = (int)relativePoint.Y;

Bitmap Screenshot = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(Screenshot);
// snip wanted area
G.CopyFromScreen(X, Y, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

string fileName = "C:\\myCapture.bmp";
System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
Screenshot.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
fs.Close();
```

**My problem:**

The `Width` and `Height` appear to be bad (false values).
The screenshot produced appear to use bad coordinates.

**My screenshot:**

[image: My screenshot]

**What I expect:**

[image: Desired screenshot]

Why do I get this result?
I tried in Release mode, and without Visual Studio, result is the same.

Comment: You could get some ideas from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094494/how-make-a-screenshot-of-uielement-in-wpf

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A screenshot is a shot of the screen... *everything* on the screen. What you want is to save an image from a single `UIElement` and you can do that using the [`RenderTargetBitmap.Render` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This method takes a `Visual` input parameter and luckily, that is one of the base classes for all `UIElement`s. So assuming that you want to save a .png file, you could do this:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = 
    new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
renderTargetBitmap.Render(yourMapControl); 
PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
{
    pngImage.Save(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to show this `pngImage` in `image` control instead of saving `pngImage`

Comment: @UzairAli, that's far simpler. Just use the control that you want to display as the `Visual` of a `VisualBrush`. See the [`VisualBrush` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information.

Comment: `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds` will help you get the dimensions for any `Visual`. It returns `Rect`, whose `Width` and `Height` are doubles; you need convert them using `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `PixelFormats.Pbgra32` is the only supported format here. You may specify it more implicitly as `PixelFormats.Default`.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code with datagrid but I got blank image. Isn't datagrid supported?

Comment: int width = Convert.ToInt32(dtgEvolucaoPendenciasDiretoria.ActualWidth);

int height = Convert.ToInt32(dtgEvolucaoPendenciasDiretoria.ActualHeight);

RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();

renderTargetBitmap.Render(dtgEvolucaoPendenciasDiretoria);      
          
pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"D:\Users\dtgEvolucaoPendenciasDiretoria.bmp"))
{
    pngImage.Save(fileStream);
}

Comment: Sorry, I don't know... I've never tried it. If it's not too late, try asking a new question and add a link to this one for background information.

Comment: @Sheridan How to do it in MVVM?

Comment: @grv_9098, there is no UI-based code in my example. You can call that from your View Models, although I'd put that code into some kind of a Service or Manager class that the View Models have access to.

Comment: I want to take screenshot from a windows form host but above answer does not take of it. How can I take screenshot from a windows form host?

Comment: @MohammadrezaKashi, if you read this answer, you will see that despite the question title, it does not relate to taking screenshots. Please ask a new question. Thanks.