# Get the children of the object present

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I'm having a **Grid** and in that grid m having a scroll-able content and in that having a chartgrid

**Xaml Code**

```
   <TabItem x:Name="Charts" Header="  Company Charts " TabIndex="0" IsSelected="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerDN" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Transparent" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Expression_Dark">
                        <Grid Name="OuterGridChart">
                            <Grid x:Name="ChartGrid"  Margin="10" Background="Transparent" >
```

**CS CODE**

```
 private void ExecuteExportSingleChartToPdf(object obj)
    {
        var values = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<object>)(obj)).ToList();
         Grid grid1 = values[0] as Grid;
```

above ExecuteExportSingleChartToPdf is a delegate command for a button

I'm able to generate a image temporarily  bt the issue is that only the current selected tab is generated as image

1. Wanna to have both the grid-> children (tabcontrol) -> grid
2. access the  children

And the chart grid (tabcontrol) ..charts are displayed in row and coloumn, want to have the row wise image to be saved as one.

Comment: Please don't use all capital letters in your title... it gives the impression that you're shouting.

Comment: Yes i agree with Sheridan further more you should really try to make some sense . 

What is it your asking , how to get the content of each TabItem ?

Comment: sorry for this.
wat i want is toh have the children of grid
in grid i have following : 2 tab control, and in each tab there's again a grid
In 2nd tab: of chart grid.
there's row and coloumn.. i want to have the whole row to be accessed and make it a image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an image from any `Visual` element (virtually all controls extend the `Visual` class) using just a few lines of code. Rather than repeat myself again, please refer to my answer to the [How to take a screenshot of a WPF control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466482/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-wpf-control/24478299#24478299) question to find out how to do that.

Now all you need to do is to rearrange your XAML so that you have all of your row controls *in one control*. Therefore, I would recommend that you define a new `Grid` control with however many columns that you need in your relevant `Grid` row... you can use the [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx) to align the new `Grid` columns with any outer columns if need be.

Finally, just pass a reference to your new `Grid` to the code from the linked question and you will have an `Image` of your controls.