# DrawToBitmap returns black Image from UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controls, drawtobitmap

My first post here so here goes,

i have a UserControl with about 30 controls (labels, textboxes etc).
Now i would like to make a "screenshot" of it.
So i used the "DrawToBitmap" method from the UserControl.

Here some samplecode

```
//this is the UserControl with the about 30 controls    
var sampleusercontrol = new SampleUserControl();

var bmp = new Bitmap(sampleusercontrol.Width, sampleusercontrol.Height);
sampleusercontrol.DrawToBitmap(bmp, sampleusercontrol.Bounds);
```

if i run this code, it returns me a black image all the time.
I have no clue why. Please help!

Edit:

Forgot to say that the UserControl is a WinForms UserControl

Comment: I have had the same problem. For me, the solution was to do - sampleusercontrol.Arrange(0, 0, sampleusercontrol.Width, sampleusercontrol.height) before I created the bitmap. I have no idea why this worked, but it did...

Comment: [`DrawToBitmap`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4441da5479e7a6f8) simply sending `WM_PRINT` message. `Arrange` is wpf function, why not to [do it in the right way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24478299/1997232) ?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say that the usercontrol i am talking about, is a winforms usercontrol

Comment: Bounds is simply the wrong rectangle, use sampleusercontrol.DisplayRectangle instead.

Comment: To add to Hans' comment: `Bounds` is 'located' at the control's `Location`, so unless it sits at the screen origin you will miss much or all of the image. Depending on whether the control is scrolled or not you may go for `ClientRectangle` for the visible portion or `DisplayRectangle` for the full content including portions that are not visible atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had been working for me for years until it started returning a black image last week in production. Interestingly, it was just after we applied a new windows patch. I was able to find this posting about the issue:

[KB3057839 Has Broken Windows Forms Control.DrawToBitmap() When Called from Application Launched From Windows Service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d690398-1f91-4fbd-82fa-4b663c3b558f/kb3057839-has-broken-windows-forms-controldrawtobitmap-when-called-from-application-launched-from?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

You didn't mention how that winforms control was being created, but in the first case it was from a winforms app launched by a service. There is also a case on the Telerik site where the control was instantiated server-side by IIS to create a PDF file:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/export-to-pdf-597e04c01b39

Try checking for the patch KB3057839 and rolling it back for a short term fix. Hopefully Microsoft will respond with a fix or a workaround going forward.

Comment: The Windows KB3057839 update broken numerous software ranging from Putty, Telerik, GE software, Quicken 2015, and various others I'm not mentioning.

Comment: I was able to confirm that the new patch KB3070102 overrides the previous one and fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  The latest round of ms patches corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the control has been loaded.

I was struggling with this, but it turned out the control was in another tab and wouldnt display correctly until I had clicked on the tab, then run `DrawToBitmap`.