# How to get the screen shot of a window other than the main one of certain specific program in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

I am using c# WPF application to get the screen shot of my application opened by ignoring the main screen i.e WPF Application output screen. Basically I want to get the screenshot of the backend application rather than the front window on which my user will be working to press the button for screenshot etc.

Note: It doesnot matter what ever windows are opened infront of the user he might have minimized the application screen But my program is intended to get the screen shot of the application window even if it is currently minimized.

[Screenshot of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLACW.jpg)

Above one is the screenshot taken by my program but the problem is:

1. It took the screenshot of the main window i.e the WPF window. I dont want this to appear in my screen shot. My App is intended to get only the screen on which the code is written i.e the whole current background of visual studio.
2. It can take picture of any currently active window. I want it to work in a way to make my background visual studio screen active and then capture the image of that window.
   Note: My program is not intended for visual studio this is just a sample i will be using this code in some other application that is why i will be getting the current process and apply the whole procedure.

Comment: After clicking on the capture button hide the form, wait some milliseconds to allow redraw, take the screenshot and then make it visible again...

Comment: Isn't [`RenderTargetBitmap.Render`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24478299/1997232) works for minimized window?