# Custom bitmap capture that keeps formatting?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, screenshot

I have been using Bitmap to take a capture of my main form and saving it as jpeg. Unfortunately bitmap does not keep my text colour. Best way I can describe this is by images (see below). My mainform has an objectlistview which has a column coloured red. Bitmap however captures this as black text? why?

Is there any other alternative method I can use?

I have tried capturing screen and cutting out the the mainform as shown in the code below. This works great on a 1080p monitor, but not on my 4k monitor with 200% scaling, it results in the image being cut.

```
public void SaveControlImage(Form form)
        {
            string path_and_file = "C:\1.png";
            Bitmap controlBitMap = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(controlBitMap);
            g.CopyFromScreen(PointToScreen(form.Location), new Point(0, 0), form.Size);

            // example of saving to the desktop
            controlBitMap.Save(path_and_file, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

[image: How main form looks]

[image: what bitmap capture shows]

Comment: Not sure what is your problem, but there is another approach to obtain screenshots, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24478299/1997232).

Comment: Try [this class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257205/7444103), it should handle High-Dpi, provided that your app is DpiAware. See the notes there and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103).

Comment: @Jimi I tried this class. Unfortunately no matter what I pass in it seems like its printing a blank form. No labels, panels, groupboxes are being drawn. Any suggestions?

Comment: So, if you call `var bitmap = ControlPrinter.ScrollableControlToBitmap(this, true, true);` from the Form you want to print, you get back a *blank Image*? That's not possible. Show what code you're using and when/where/how you're calling it.

Comment: @Jimi I made a new .cs with the class and that builds fine. this is in my main form   `var bitmap = ControlPrinter.ScrollableControlToBitmap(this, true, true);
            bitmap.Save(path_and_file, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);`

 What ends up showing is this:

[![image][1]][1]

I have also tried passing in panels and other types of controls and none of them unfortunately yield in any difference. 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrJRR.png

Comment: Right. Build a new Form, add some random controls to it. Also, add two Buttons and two PictureBoxes. Set the PictureBoxes `.SizeMode = Zoom`. In the first Button.Click handler, add: `pictureBox1.Image = ControlPrinter.ScrollableControlToBitmap(this, true, true);`, in the other Button, `var bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height); this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.Bounds); pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;`. See what you get in the IDE.

Comment: @Jimi button1 does not do anything to picturebox1
button2 creates some sort of cropped image of of the form in picturebox 2
https://i.imgur.com/1S5p1XE.png

Is this expected?

It is built with .net core 5.0

Comment: @Jimi tried again with net framework 4.8. Same result, calling controlprinter does not yield in any results. Bitmap works... but has its issues